# Insert CalendarEvent to other calendar than "primary"

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

How may I insert a CalendarEvent to a specific calendar given by its Id?

In my app I'm scanning all calendars and adding them to an ArrayList like this:

```
for (CalendarListEntry calendarEntry : this.calendars.getItems()) {
      this.calendarIDs.add(calendarEntry.getId());
}
```

The only code fragment I found is:

```
Event createdEvent = service.events().insert("primary", event).execute();
```

I tried to put the feed url instead of *"private"*, like

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/<id_here>%40group.calendar.google.com/private/full
```

but then I got a

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Found",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  }],
  "message" : "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: You can check Your example usage in "APIs Explorer". Link for calendar methods: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/. Test it - maybe You find the way after that.

Comment: It looks like you might be mixing versions - that feed URL is from v2, but the JSON response is v3. Can you clarify where in your code that URL is from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these code snippets:

Snippet1:

```
public void authenticate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    List <String> scopes = new LinkedList<String>();
    scopes.add(scope);
    AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorize = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(client_id, redirect_uri, scopes);
    authorize.setRedirectUri(redirect_uri);
    String authorize_url              = authorize.build();
    log.info(authorize_url);
    response.sendRedirect(authorize_url);
}
```

Snippet one takes care of OAuth and redirects the program to the redirect uri. The values of the variables scope, client_id, cliend_secret and scope they come from Google api console.

Snippet 2:

```
public void importCalendarList(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String code = request.getParameter("code");
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleTokenResponse res = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(transport, jsonFactory, client_id, client_secret, code, redirect_uri).execute();
    ]String accessToken = res.getAccessToken();
    Calendar.Builder builder = new Calendar.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, null);  
    builder.setCalendarRequestInitializer(new CalendarRequestInitializer(accessToken));
    Calendar calendarService = builder.build();
    Calendar.CalendarList.List list = calendarService.calendarList().list();
    list.setOauthToken(accessToken);
    List <CalendarListEntry>list1=list.execute().getItems();
    String id = list1.get(0).getId();
    p.write(id);

    for(CalendarListEntry temp:list1) {
        p.println(temp.getSummary());
        temp.getId();
    }

    Event e = new Event();

    e.setSummary("Test event");
    e.setLocation("Adaptavant");

    Date startDate = new Date();
    Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
    DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    e.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
    DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    e.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));
    Event insertedEvent = calendarService.events().insert(id, e).setOauthToken(accessToken).execute();

    p.println(insertedEvent.getId());
```

}

Snippet two gets the list of calendars and gets the id of one of them and creates an event in that calendar. If you want to add events to the primary calendar the primary calendar's id is the gmail id that is used to log in.

Further documentation is found here:

https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when the user is a google user but he isn't connecte to google plus.

It should also explode in this call: service.people().get("me").execute();